# How to outer join multiple instances of same table

Tags: sql-server, join

[image]

I am having two tables i.e. tbl_Certificates and tbl_Employees.
And certifiate are pepared and apprvoved by employees. In some cases preparedBy and approvdby attribute could be NULL, But still i want all certificate list.
Expected result is in the above image.
I know this is very basic question.
Thanks In advance...:)

Comment: Share your sql script

Comment: What you already tried?

Comment: I get can get required result using inner query. But I need solution using joins

Comment: What is reason for joins if your inner query slolution works?

Comment: I need to write 4 inner queries for it... And that's not a feasible solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Certificates AS Certs
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Employees AS PreparedBy ON Certs.PrepareById=PreparedBy.Id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Employees AS ApprovedBy ON Certs.ApprovedById=ApprovedBy.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

To be short: you just do it

```
select
    cert.id                 as "CertificateId"
    ,preparedBy.Name        as "PreparedBy"
    ,preparedBy.Designation as "Prepared By Designation"
    ,approvedBy.Name        as "ApprovedBy"
    ,approvedBy.Designation as "Approved By Designation"
from
    tbl_Certificates cert
    left outer join tbl_Employees preparedBy
        on preparedBy.id = cert.PreparedById
    left outer join tbl_Employees approvedBy
        on preparedBy.id = cert.ApprovedById
```